# Use wikipedia tables to rename files

Tags: wikipedia

I want to make a program that given a series name will rename my files to the episode names from Wikipedia. I though of maybe getting the episode list to a table or some data structure and renaming the files. Can it be done, and if so, how can I get the episode list form Wikipedia?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the text of a Wikipedia article, you can use [the API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) for that.

For example, to get the article HTML (enclosed in XML), you can use a request like:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=parse&page=List%20of%20Breaking%20Bad%20episodes

If you'd prefer to work with wikitext instead of HTML, the query would be something like:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&titles=List%20of%20Breaking%20Bad%20episodes&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

Comment: and if I want to get list for other series I just replace the titles parameter the the series I want right?

Comment: @aizen92 Yeah, assuming all the articles follow the same naming convention (which they should).

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving data from wikipedia to do this is fairly easy. I would go for using python with 
retrieving the page with `urllib2` or [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) or [mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/). There is probably similar functionality in your favourite programming language. Analyse the retrieved page with [BeautifulSoup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and use that to retrieve the names.

What is more probably more difficult is mapping your local filenames to that table unless your original files already have something like S1E7 you would not know which episode name to pick from the table you created.

Comment: well, each season will have a folder, and mostly i'll be using it for anime series, so there wont be seasons and such, anyway I will check it

Comment: Getting the whole page directly is not a good idea, using the API is much better.

Comment: @svick, cool, didn't know that. Now I wonder if that API existed when I wrote my download back in 2002 or that I missed the API docs even then.

Comment: @Anthon In 2002? You mean at the time when Wikipedia didn't actually use the current software (MediaWiki) yet? No, I think there wasn't any API at the time. And the API page on mediawiki.org [dates back only to 2006](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=API:Main_page&oldid=94126).